# Return a name based on no value present in following column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Have a spreadsheet that I want to automate.  Hoping to pull the data from an array where all I am looking for are the names that have no values present -  IE the ones who work have a 1 in the next column for that day, and the ones who are off have nothing in the following column. If possible, would like it to check whether there is data present, and then move on to the next name.  I have tried if statements only to get spill errors as well as V and XLookups with no progress.

The table I want to pull from

[image]

Want it to return the name into column one, only want it to return names where no value is present in SAT NITE/SUN column

[image]

Comment: It would help if you would [edit] the post and include a [mark down table](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/) with a small mock up of the data and expected output.  It is a lot easier to get a sense of what you need/want with an actual demo of data and not just words.

Comment: Post is edited, threw in screenshots as i'm not familiar with stack overflow expectations.  Sorry about that!

Comment: It is easier with mark down tables so we can copy paste.  But use FILTER().

Answer (score 1):

The [FILTER function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) allows you to filter a range of data based on criteria you define.  You can combine multiple criteria using `*` for "and", or `+` for "or".

#### Value in B:B

Filter Column A where there is a value in Column B

```
=FILTER(A:A,B:B<>"")
```

[image]

#### Value in B:B or C:C

Filter column A where there is a value in either column B or column C

```
=FILTER(A:A,(B:B<>"")+(B:B<>""))
```

[image]

#### Value in B:B and C:C

Filter column A where there is a value in both column B and column C

```
=FILTER(A:A,(B:B<>"")*(B:B<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: I think the formula should have been `=FILTER(A:A,(B:B<>"")*(C:C<>""))`

Comment: OP stated that they only wanted *"it to return names where no value is present in SAT NITE/SUN column"*.  However, I'll edit it to show additional variations, for future travelers.

Comment: Should probably include a note or mention somewhere regarding the difference between `<>""` vs `len()<>0` vs isblank() or isempty().